# How to get compass to update .css file and display the new content without manual synchronise

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, webstorm, compass

I am using WebStorm EAP 142.4723. I can create .scss and get them to output to the .css files in a css directory.

However, to view the change contents in the .css file I manually have to sync the file to see the changes.

When I create a Filewatcher using P:\Ruby22-x64\bin\scss.bat, the file is updated in realtime with its contents displayed without having to sync manually.

### config.rb

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv `scss sass`
```

### screenshot of compass FileWatcher

[image: Compass Filewatcher]

What arguments should I pass to get the contents to be displayed immediately?

Thanks

Comment: Last field: `Output paths to refresh` -- point it to actual file(s) and not folder.

Comment: J:/workspace/epimss/dart/epimss_app/sass/*.css does NOT work. Same result.

Comment: It should be exact file name -- no masks at all. If more than one -- should be listed separated by `:`, e.g. (from TypeScript file watcher) `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js.map`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, that method does not scales well for many files. I can accomplish the same thing using scss.bat and changing the Arguments in the UI above. I think I will use the scss.bat instead until I find some other way. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "many files". I mean -- the original idea of File Watcher is to compile only changed files **one by one** (be it standalone file .. or main file that has lots of includes; if partial file is modified then main (root) file gets compiled). Why recompile whole folder if other files had no changes? For such setup it would probably be better to use Gulp/Grunt task.